# ADK FTDI USB driver

Tags: android, drivers, adk

I'm trying to get the android ADK example applications working. The java stuff works fine. The arduino code compiles with no problems.

The one issue I'm having is that the ADK board is not being detected at all on my OSX even though I have the FTDI drivers installed.

I tried setting up the same thing under windows and there the board is recognized as an "Unknown Device" but even if I manually select the FTDI driver inf file windows will claim that it's not the proper driver for the ADK board.

Have any of you gotten this working? Is there something I'm missing?

UPDATE:

Spent some time working with some hardware buddies of mine and our conclusion - it's a bad chip. So thanks to everyone who put in their 2c. I really appreciate it. And I reaffirm my commitment to software over hardware ;)

Comment: This is the Google Android ADK board from Google IO. FTDI chip is impossible to read but i think its 1051-8 C1519301 FT232RL. I'll check the electronics stackexchange too thanks ;)

Comment: @walta Sorry I didn't edit my message and just deleted.  I misread your question, I though you were talking about Arduino.  It's been a long week :).  What version of windows are you using?

Comment: @walta well color me stupid - you WERE talking about arduino AND android.  Heh, didn't realize google had an ADK for arduino.  Very cool.  So your sketches run fine, but when you attach the shield it stops working?

Comment: @SRM yeah - made it kinda a toss up for which forum to put it in. Supre cool stuff - io from the phone to the board and back. Sketch compiles and verifies fine (I'm just compiling the demo that came with the board). The board came pre-programmed and I just tested it with the phone so even the android-board link works. The only 1 tiny thing getting in the way of pure awesomeness is that the computer can't program the board.

Comment: The docs say the board is a Mega 2560. I have the mega drivers on both windows and osx but on osx the board isn't detected when I plug it in (or maybe I just don't know where to look) and on windows I can see an unknown usb device, but none of the mega drivers work work.

Comment: Try posting the VID/PID of the 'unknown usb device'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some time working with some hardware buddies of mine and our conclusion - it's a bad chip. So thanks to everyone who put in their 2c. I really appreciate it. And I reaffirm my commitment to software over hardware ;)